# where can i find directory i have created using hadoop fs -mkdir in my ubuntu file system

Tags: java, database, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

i am new to hadoop , i have created directory using

```
 hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/vinayak
```

where is this folder located in my file system , i am using **ubuntu** 18.04.

i am new to hadoop and unfamiliar to its architecture

when i tried  `hadoop fs -ls /` 
 i get this 
**output :**

```
Found 1 items
drwxr-xr-x   - hadoopuser supergroup          0 2019-06-18 11:04 /user
```

where are this directory found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't find that directory in your local (ubuntu) filesystem. You'll have to work with HDFS using its command line utilities (hdfs dfs ...).

Comment: What this means file is created in small pieces of data files

Comment: Where did you get that?

Comment: No where just thought that Because i was unable to find directory but I found many unsupported files

Comment: You might want to take a look at this page https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsDesign.html . The way it works, you have a NameNode service (userspace java process) that keeps all filesystem metadata in its memory (and in a file called fsimage). So, your HDFS directory is physically stored in just those two places - NameNode memory and fsimage file.